# How do I sync beyond 30 days with BES

Tags: synchronization, blackberry, calendar, bes

BES only syncs the last 30 days worth of calendar appointments.

I need to change this to sync more than 30 days, e.g. 6 months for example.

I read a workaround which involves disabling the wireless sync, syncing with the Blackberry Desktop software and then re-enabling the wireless sync.  This would not work, as the 30 day setting would still apply to calendar appointments going forwards.

**How can I set BES up to sync more than 30 days worth of calendar appointments?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible with the current releases of BES. I think the only option is what you mentioned in your question. You can try the solution through the Blackberry desktop application [here](http://www.blackberry.com/btsc/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=KB18625&sliceId=1&docTypeID=DT_SUPPORTISSUE_1_1&dialogID=568624370&stateId=0%200%20568620208) however it may not hold the effect for your wireless sync.

Answer (score 0):

I am runing BES 5.0 and BES Express 5.0 and can tell you that our calendars definately sync beyond 30 days.

What version of BES are you using?